# Github upload is bigger than my project

Tags: android, github, upload

I just uploaded my project to Github and it was 21Mib. My .apk file (the executable) is 2.87MB. What is happening here? I'm now concerned that my app will be a bigger download than I anticipated if I put it on the app store. Thanks.

Comment: There's absolutely no way we could tell unless you added a link to the github project so we could look.

Comment: I can't do that sorry. The .apk file is what I go by for how big the download will be on the Google app store isn't it? That is my only concern. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git does not only store the files you see in your folder. It stores the history of every file.
Thats the reason why it needs more space. But you will only upload your current .apk file to app store with its 2.87MB.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following:

- Make sure you disabled debugging flat from manifest file by setting android:debuggable="false"
- When uploading to Github, remove 'bin' and 'gen' folder as they are temporary folders
- Check if there are any big image/other files which are being packed in .apk (Check your asset and other data folders)
- Check if you are adding additional library in your project.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Git contains the history of previous versions of code

.git file will be large in size which maintains  previous data